# AKNodeOutputPlot increase speed?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am using AudioKit for an iOS app. Right now everything is working well for me. However I am having trouble customizing the AKNodeOutputPlot animation. When using AKNodeOutputPlot how do you increase its speed? Basically it takes x seconds to fill its view. How can I get it do it in x/2 seconds with a view of the same size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a rolling plot, in which case do:

```
plot.setRollingHistoryLength(<#T##historyLength: Int32##Int32#>)
```

Comment: Where in the docs would I find that? Under rolling plot? Also thanks for helping! I have been using this so far http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AudioKit/3.7.1/index.html

Comment: Ok I figured it out. AKNodeOutputPlot is a subclass of EZAudioPlot. So EZAudioPlot will have all of the necessary methods that I need.

Comment: @iOSGuy93892 Glad you got it straight.  Its been on our list to modernize the graphing a bit, so maybe soon it will be even better.

Comment: Hate to bother you again, but is there a simple way to get rid of the line in the middle when the plot starts (there is a sort of blank line in the rolling plots that gets filled from left to right)? It is proving to be frustrating to get rid of since all of the UIBezier paths are on the same layer (or at least in my mind, it seems like you are using multiple UIBezier paths on a single CAShape layer). Removing it also removes all of the plotted points.

Comment: @iOSGuy93892 I am sure you can edit the source to do that but there's not an interface to prescribe that change. The plots are meant to be starting points and we fully expect people to roll their own to get exactly what they want. But, like I said, we are trying to modernize things so we'll keep that in mind for the next iteration.